# Extract Date from a comment string

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql, casting

I am wondering what the best way is to extract the date and year from the following string structure:

Example: 01/01/2023: This is the comment which can vary in length

I am attempting to extract everything from the ":" which would be the date and the yyyy which would be the year (2023)

I have attempted to use the following syntax:

```
YEAR(CAST(CAST(LEFT(CD.Comments,10) AS DATE) AS varchar)) = ('2023')
```

to extract the year which returns the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Which SQL are you using?  The standard date format is YYYY/MM/DD.

Comment: Hello Tim, I am using SQL server 2014.... The column i am attempting to extract from is set as varchar(512)

Comment: is your date always in this format `01/01/2023`? And is it in `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Comment: If you really only want the extract the year and the date format is fixed (with zero-padded day and month values), perhaps you just need `SUBSTRING(CD.Comments, 7,4) = '2023'`. Optionally convert to `INT` if you prefer, and/or pre-validate with a conditional `LEN(CD.Comments) >= 10` or `CD.Comments LIKE '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]:%'` if there is a need.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `CAST(...) AS DATE`, do `CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(CD.Comments,10),101)`. The MM/DD/YYYY format is format number 101.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp